# Can you substitute or delete between commas (or any arbitrary character) in vi/vim?

Tags: vim

For example, I have text like this:

```
I talked to a friend, I hiked a mountain, I am working with blah blah,
```

And I want to delete or substitute `I hiked a mountain`. Why doesn't `ci,` or `di,` work? Is there a way to grab, substitute, or delete between commas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

there are plugins to let you create customized text object. without installing plugins, assume your cursor is between two commas, you could do:

```
T,c,
```

or

```
t,c,
```

to simulate your `ci,` for `di,` change the above `c` into `d`

related help doc:

```
:h t
:h T
:h ,
```

Comment: When I looked at this I thought "Shouldn't it be `T,ct,`"?
Took me a second to realize this was `,` as in repeat search.

Answer (score 9):

There are a bunch of plugins that help you create custom text-objects like [textobjectify](https://github.com/paradigm/TextObjectify).

I've had the following snippet in my `vimrc` for quite a while and it never failed me:

```
for char in [ '_', '.', ':', ',', ';', '<bar>', '/', '<bslash>', '*', '+', '%' ]
  execute 'xnoremap i' . char . ' :<C-u>normal! T' . char . 'vt' . char . '<CR>'
  execute 'onoremap i' . char . ' :normal vi' . char . '<CR>'
  execute 'xnoremap a' . char . ' :<C-u>normal! F' . char . 'vf' . char . '<CR>'
  execute 'onoremap a' . char . ' :normal va' . char . '<CR>'
endfor
```

It creates all the custom operator-pending mappings required for `di,`, `vi%`, `ci:`, `ya|` and so on.

And it's easy to add new delimiters.

And I have cute smileys in my `vimrc`.

--- EDIT ---

FWIW, this snippet and all the other custom text objects I have added to my config over the years can be found [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/romainl/c0a8b57a36aec71a986f1120e1931f20).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it's amazing

Answer (score 3):

If you are in a section like that you could use `T,ct,`.

Or you if you want to install a plugin like [vim-argumentative](https://github.com/PeterRincker/vim-argumentative) allows you to use `ci,` and `di,`

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to patch Vim for this feature, there was a proposal a while back (including a mostly working patch) to allow you to match arbitrary characters. In your example it would be `cim,` for "change inside matched comma". See https://groups.google.com/d/topic/vim_dev/pZxLAAXxk0M/discussion for the discussion and a few versions of the patch. I've been using it a long time and the only problem I've encountered is in visual mode; but then again, I don't use the feature as often as I expected to.

Answer (score 0):

Using `targets.vim`:

- `da,` to delete complete sentence and leaving one comma.
- `ci,` to change inside the commas.