# Change text inside any character (like ci')

Tags: vim

Is it possible to change inside any character?

For example I can change inside `'` by using `ci'`.

I want to change inside the `-` character, like this:

```
--I want to change inside this --
```

I am unable to do this with `ci-`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you substitute or delete between commas (or any arbitrary character) in vi/vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856240/can-you-substitute-or-delete-between-commas-or-any-arbitrary-character-in-vi-v)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible by default but you can create your own text-objects.
Check this plugin: [targets.vim](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim)
Also have a look at `:help operator` and `:help mapmode-o`

Long story short, this seems to do the trick: `:omap i- :<C-u>normal!T-vt-<CR>`